# Error while import in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I have created a sample typescript jquery project and I am facing issue while import

error is:

> require.js:143 Uncaught Error: Module name "ajaxLib" has not been
>   loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

home.ts:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />

import { AjaxContainer } from "./ajaxLib";
module Home {
    export class HomeContainer {
        private content: HTMLElement;

        constructor(value?: any) {
            // document.body.innerHTML = value;
            var animal = new AjaxContainer();
            var el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('grid1');
            $(el).css({"color": "blue" });
        }
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var object1 = new Home.HomeContainer("ram");
}
```

Complete project is on github : https://github.com/focode/typescriptJquery/tree/master

Also I am successfully able to use jquery.

After changing module to amd the converted js file now includes define

```
define(["require", "exports", "./ajaxLib"], function (require, exports, ajaxLib_1) {
    "use strict";
    var Home;
    (function (Home) {
        var HomeContainer = (function () {
            function HomeContainer(value) {
                var animal = new ajaxLib_1.AjaxContainer();
                var el = document.getElementById('grid1');
                $(el).css({ "color": "blue" });
            }
            return HomeContainer;
        }());
        Home.HomeContainer = HomeContainer;
    })(Home || (Home = {}));
    window.onload = function () {
        var object1 = new Home.HomeContainer("ram");
    };
});
```

but on browser console I am getting:

```
require.js:143 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require, exports, ajaxLib_1) {
    "use strict";
    var Home;
    (function (Home) {
        var HomeContainer = (function () {
            function HomeContainer(value) {
                var animal = new ajaxLib_1.AjaxContainer();
                var el = document.getElementById('grid1');
                $(el).css({ "color": "blue" });
            }
            return HomeContainer;
        }());
        Home.HomeContainer = HomeContainer;
    })(Home || (Home = {}));
    window.onload = function () {
        var object1 = new Home.HomeContainer("ram");
    };
}
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
```

Comment: you're using requirejs (AMD) on the front end but typescript is compiling to commonjs modules. The `ajaxLib` library is not declaring an AMD module as a result and it falls over. Change your `modules` option in `tsconfig.json` to use `amd`.

Comment: Hi Dan, can you tell me how can I do that, I am new to typescript

Comment: I just told you. Modify the `modules` option in the `tsconfig.json` file to say `amd` and not `commonjs`.

Comment: Hi Dan, I did the change , but still I am getting the same error , I have updated the github with this change

Comment: Problem is solved ... I was using jquery first and then requirejs , I changed the order and it got resolved . Code is updated on my github.com/focode